# How to get only file name in 'for' batch command and not file extension

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When using this code to upload video's to YouTube, the title that gets named has the file extension at the end (in this case .mp4)

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do python --file="%%f" --title="%%f"
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but maybe you should remove the extension from the string you pass the `--title` option

Comment: exactly as @jphager2 said. "here's a red ball to hold. why are you holding a red ball?" you're passing the full filename for the title, which is going to include the .mp4 extension. you need to filter that out.

Comment: It's used for Python to recognize the title to be used in the video, the default value is "Test title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `for %%f in (*.csv) do echo "%%~nf"`

for more info do a `for /?` .. this is the part that you would liek to see

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

Comment: Doesn't change the uploaded title

Comment: for %%f in (*.mp4) do python C:\Users\User\Desktop\YouTube.py --file="%%f" --title="%%~fI" I'm using a bat file

Comment: Updated my answer . Sorry there was an error . This has worked for me. I ran. This will work.

Comment: NO . I dont have python installed. I just gave you a working code which will fetch the filename only and not the extension. You can make the necessary changes in your code. Just replace --title="%%f" with --title="%%~nf"