# How do I remove file extension of directories in sub directories?

Tags: windows, cmd, file-io, directory, batch-rename

I use google drive official application called "Backup and Sync from Google".

Directories with file extension can cause syncing error.

So I am trying to remove file extension of any directory.

```
for /r /d %x in (*.mp4) do ren "%x" 123
```

This can change all directories name to "123", which can remove file extensions but also change directories name.

Now I want to keep the directories name the same, only remove file extension of directories.

Not knowing what to replace "123" with in the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get only file name in 'for' batch command and not file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919795/how-to-get-only-file-name-in-for-batch-command-and-not-file-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, nice.

```
for /r /d %i in (*.mp4) do ren "%i" "%~ni"
```